# How can I encode this array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, dom

the following code gets content and images from posts. A post has 1 content and many images.

I succesfully encoded $content but I can not do the same with $filtered (I guess). Those values will be sent through a form, thats why I encoded it.

The problem is that I can't get the encoding working on $filtered.

```
<?php

$varcontent[$i]["content"] = $encoded;
$varcontent[$i]["images"] = $filtered; 


?>
```

Comment: I can see, in your original source, where you are encoding $content.  Where are you encoding $filtered?

Comment: I am not. This is what I am trying because it gives me error. It says it's an array.

Comment: You'll have to save the files to send them somewhere, or base64 encode the images into strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$varcontent[$i]["content"] = $encoded;

foreach($varcontent[$i]["images"] as $image){
       $images .= $image;
}

$varcontent[$i]["images"] = htmlentities($images, ENT_QUOTES); //or whatever filter means
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to stringify your array, then encode it. This way you will be able to send it through a text protocoll.